# Android application does not relaunch when navigating to the home screen

Tags: android, android-launcher

We have a launcher application that works fine on older versions of Android. We have a device that is running Android 5.1, and are running into issues.

When pressing the back button from within the application, we allow the user to go to the settings page. Pressing the home key re-launches the application. Pressing the back button on other devices also relaunches the application.

On the new device, pressing the back button allows us to navigate to the Android home page. It does not launch the application.

We are overriding the back button like so:

```
@override
public void onBackPressed() {

   // Display the password prompt if required
   if (PreferencesManager.isPasswordPresent()) {
   LeaveApplicationPasswordDialogFragment dialog = LeaveApplicationPasswordDialogFragment.getInstance();
   dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "password");
}
else {
   // Prompt whether we are about to leave the app
   LeaveApplicationDialogFragment dialog = null;
   MyApplication application = (MyApplication ) 
   getApplication();
   if (application.isDefaultLauncher()) {
      dialog = LeaveApplicationDialogFragment.getInstance("Are you sure you want to leave ** to access the device's settings?");
   }
   else {
      dialog = LeaveApplicationDialogFragment.getInstance("Are you sure you want to leave ***");
   }  
   dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "leaving");

   }

}
```

In the dialog fragment, we accept the confirmation and process it like so:

```
public void exitToSettings() {
   GUIAndroidTouchBaseActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
   shutdownOperations();
   finish();

}
```

Per some research and other threads, I worked with our exit method like so:

```
public void exitToSettings() {

   Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

   GUIAndroidTouchBaseActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
   shutdownOperations();
   finish();

}
```

No dice. Same behavior.

What am I missing? Is there something in OS 5.1 that's overriding our launcher? Again, pressing the home button launches the app as expected. Navigating to the home page from the settings page by pressing the back button does not.

What we have works on other devices and OSs. We've had no issue with 4.1 and 6.1.

We are also overriding the back button like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent KEvent) {

  int deviceid = KEvent.getDeviceId();

  //Making sure not processing same key again
  if (KEvent.getRepeatCount() != 0) {
     return true;
  }

  if (!SettingsOpened) {
     int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();

     // "Esc" key can not be stooped id diveceid is non zero because it can be back key of android
     if (KEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && deviceid != 0) {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, KEvent);
     }

     if (keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        String key = KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode); //wont work in version 11 or less

        if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENVELOPE) {
           Matcher matcher = KEYCODE_PATTERN.matcher(key);
           if (matcher.matches() || ExternalKeyboard.keyMatches(KEvent)) {
              int keyunicode = KEvent.getUnicodeChar(KEvent.getMetaState());
              char character = (char) keyunicode;

              //toast.makeText(this, "onKeyDown" + _lastChar + repeatcount, toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              _lastChar = character;
              _actionDown = true;
              ExternalKeyboard.KeyboardAddChar(character);
           }
        }
     }
     return true;
  }
  else {
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, KEvent);
  }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try overriding onKeyDown as well for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK?

Comment: We already are:

Comment: I have found that adding android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false" to the Manifist causes the app to launch when navigating back to home. Unfortunately, it seems to 'hang' on a black screen for varying lengths of times, and sometimes indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false"
to my manifest took care of it.